# Unresolved extern crate Rocket after adding it to patch.crates-io

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-rocket

I have added the `rocket = { version = "0.5.0-rc.1", features = ["json"] }` to the Cargo.toml under `[dependencies]` & I'm using the below in the main.rs file:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket;
```

It compiles & works fine. But now I want to use a fork of rocket so I add to the Cargo.toml:

```
[patch.crates-io]
rocket = { git = "https://github.com/LIT-Protocol/Rocket", branch = "feature/port-reuse" }
```

But now the **rust-analyzer** error "unresolved extern crate" for:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket;
```

How can I resolve this? Is there something else that I have to add to the Cargo.toml apart from the rocket patch that I added?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Have you by chance *removed* it from your `[dependencies]` when adding it to `[patch.crates-io]`? You need it in both. Also you could just use a git dependency directly, you don't have to patch.